# Taylor series of $e^z$ at point $z_0 = 1+i$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

I solved this over a year ago but fail to do so now. I remember that for problems like this one can use $e^z = e^{z_0}e^{z-(z_0)}$.
I can see the answer right away if I had $z_0 = \pi i$. But in my case, with $z_0 = 1+i$, I get stuck or at least I am feeling unsure if this is the best way to write the answer.

$$ \begin{align} e^z & = e^{1+i}e^{z-(1+i)} \\ 
 & = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{1+i}}{k!} (z-(1+i))^k
\end {align}$$

This should be what I was looking for (solved it now that I wrote it down carefully here).
Since I already wrote this, any remarks?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the original post, the main idea here is
$$e^z = e^{1+i}e^{z-(1+i)}.$$

Nothing else to do here.

Answer (score 2):

No trick needed. From the derivative of the exponential, the Taylor formula says

$$e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{1+i}\frac{(z-(1+i))^n}{n!}.$$

Comment: This is straight forward, true. I was not even considering this because often this will get messy and it is easier find a different approach. But certainly no problems with the exponential function.